# Is it possible to set qmake debug globally?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt4, qmake

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04, Qt 4.8.x

I have a bunch of Qt library projects and one application project. I would like to build all of them with debug information. I could modify each of the .pro file for debug information. However, I am wondering if there is an environmental variable or some global mechanism I can set to force qmake to build all the projects with debug enabled. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always write an alias for doing `qmake CONFIG+=debug` automatically.

Otherwise, replace the `release` entry in your `QT_CONFIG` variable with `debug` in the Qt config file which resides in this location on my Debian stable machine:

```
/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/qconfig.pri
```

or Archlinux:

```
/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/qconfig.pri
```

Of course, if you build Qt yourself, you can also choose the corresponding option when using the configure script:

```
-debug ............. Compile and link Qt with debugging turned on.
-debug-and-release . Compile and link two versions of Qt, with and without
                     debugging turned on (Mac only).
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for providing so many options. And thank you for a quick response. Regards.